# Getting around setter injection using mockito's @InjectMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have an abstract class with two Map fields. One I would like to mock and inject into an object of a subclass of AbstractClass for unit testing. The other I really don't care much about, but it has a setter.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    private Map<String, Object> mapToMock;
    private Map<String, Object> dontMockMe;

    private void setDontMockMe(Map<String, Object> map) {
        dontMockMe = map;
    }
}
```

When using @InjectMocks, it automatically tries to inject in the order: constructor, setter, field. It checks if it can inject in each of these places by checking types, then names if there are multiple type possibilities. This doesn't work well for me, because my mocked mapToMock is actually injected into dontMockMe via its setter. I cannot edit this abstract class. Is there any way for me to get around the setter injection? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to correct something you've written - Mockito tries constructor injection first, then it tries "setter and field" injection, where mocks can be injected EITHER via setters OR directly into fields.  Even if you didn't have this setter, you would still have the problem, because Mockito would inject your mock into both the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is a corner case, where automatic injection won't work in the way Mockito injection is currently designed. Also Mockito suffer from some shortcomings when there is multiple fields with the same types.

---

So to understand why this doesn't work let's dive a bit in the way Mockito performs injection :

1. It will try to inject dependencies via constructor injection, if it successes it won't try the following steps in order to protect the newly created instance from eventual side effects.
2. Then if constructor injection **did not** happen (no arg constructor, or object already instantiated), then Mockito will look for matches between mocks and setters. But it has to make some choices for it to happen automatically.

   1. If there is only mock of type `A` and only one setter with type `A` then setter injection will happen.
   2. If there is either multiple mocks or setters of type `A` it will try to find match using the type and the name of the mock (usually the `@Mock` field name). If matches are found then injection will happen.
3. Then if there is still some mocks left for injection, field injection might happen, using the same algorithm as with setter :

   1. If there is only mock of type `A` and only one field with type `A` then field injection will happen.
   2. If there is either multiple mocks or field of type `A` it will try to find match using the type and the name of the mock (usually the `@Mock` field name). If matches are found then injection will happen.

---

At the moment your code is stuck at stage 2.1 because there is probably only one mock available.

That being said with the current implementation of Mockito there is no real elegant solution, it is necessary to write yourself the injection code. And that is actually the wanted point with Mockito injection, if injection is too complex or weird, then you will have to write it out ; writing this boilerplate code is actually the best tool to question the current design.

Mockito injection is really designed for simple, straight designs.

In my opinion, I find wrong :

1. to mock a `Map`, a type you don't own, that might cause many problems.
2. to mock only a single map in tested object, that means your test knows too much about the inner working of the tested object.

It would benefit the design if you refactor the code and make the collaborators emerge. With clear dependencies/collaborators it will most certainly make the injection clearer too. Also the test should focus on asserting the interactions with the collaborators not how data how the implementation is done, data should only be tested as a result to a given input.